# I'm wanting to create a separate file of every member who joins the server and then be able to chose them randomly for a 'winner' command sorta thing

Tags: command, discord.js, member

So I am using discord.js or Visual studio code or whatever. and I've made a random hug command. And I would like to be able to have it so that the one that gets hugged doesn't get @ and it's just their name. I've successfully made a command similar to it, but i don't want to have to keep adding in names manually and theres no promise that the member won't change their name so it's not very reliable. 
So I guess what's in my mind is having a file that automatically updates with users leaving or joining or changing their names and then to be able to call on them randomly without @ing them.
So does anybody know how to do this and how i can call on them?

I've done it with the @, and now im at where I manually write in every member's name but I know that is going to end up tedious and their name might change and I don't want to have to worry about them changing their name.

```
case 'randhug':

        var user = message.guild.members.random();
        let dismember = ["Klemon", "Second sofira", "CloudBot"]
        let disresults = Math.floor((Math.random() * dismember.length));
        message.channel.send(`${message.author} SURPRISE huggies you, ${dismember[disresults]}!!!!!`);
        if (message.author.bot) return;    
        break;
```

The code I have now works, but isn't reliable in the sense that things change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you might find the `tag` or `username` properties of a [User](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) very valuable in this situation.

[`User.tag`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=tag) would return `Username#1234`.
[`User.username`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=username) would return `Username`.

```js
const member = message.guild.members.random();

message.channel.send(`${message.author} surprise huggies you, **${member.user.username}**!`)
  .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Wow! Thankies so much!!!! That was a lot easier than I thought! Also, I have another question. What if I wanted to have it that if I hugged a certain person it would just be their username?

Comment: Glad I could be of help! If I've answered your question, feel free to accept this answer using the checkmark to the left.